# Fade In And Out In ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm new to ActionScript 3 and I'm having a basic problem. I'm trying to fade one of my variables in and out but it's just fading in. It's tween3. Can you help?

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(3000);

timer.start();

var tween2:Tween = new Tween(main, "x", Strong.easeOut, main.x, 0, 2, true);
var tween1:Tween = new Tween(his, "alpha", None.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
var tween3:Tween = new Tween(her, "alpha", Strong.easeInOut, 0, 1, 2, true);
var tween4:Tween = new Tween(gilt, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0, 1, 2, true);

tween1.stop();
tween2.stop();
tween3.stop();
tween4.stop();

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, startTween);

function startTween(event:TimerEvent):void {

tween1.start();
tween2.start();
tween3.start();
tween4.start();
}

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, stopTimer);

function stopTimer(event:TimerEvent):void {
timer.stop();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/category/actionscript/) framework instead of tween3 because Tweenmax has lots of feature (sometimes is better than Flash Timeline) also here is your solution:

```
var t:TweenMax = new TweenMax(main,1,{ x: 100, delay:1,ease: Strong.easeOut });
t.start();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickedStage);

function onClickedStage(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
   t.stop();
}
```

Comment: The original question can be answered without changing the subject to a framework that doesn't have to be used.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of some code that does, more or less, what you're trying to do. I'm sure that you can learn from it and adapt this to your code.

To test my code make three MovieClips and put 'em on stage with instance names 'boxA', 'boxR' and 'blackbtn'  Clicking on the button will start your timer and tweens. In my case the 'boxes' are in an array amd the tweens are created in a 'for' loop, but of course, they don't have to be.

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);

blackbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startit)

var A:Array = new Array();
A.push(boxB); A.push(boxR);

function timerListener(e)
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < A.length; i++) 
    {
        new Tween(A[i], "alpha", Regular.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);
    }
}

function startit(e)
{
    timer.start();
}
```